# Timer function varies

Tags: timer, vb6

I have coded a simple program in vb6 which plays a wav file while displaying the words to the song on the screen. I use the timer function to change the pages throughout the playing of the song. Here is my problem.... When I press a command button, the wav file begins playing and the timer is activated with the timer interval set to the length that the first page of lyrics is to be displayed. Sometimes there is a short, perhaps one second or so, delay in starting the song, which results in the next page being displayed a second or so off in time. It doesn't happen every time,sometimes it's right-on, and other times its off a bit. Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `Pause 1` at the start of your script or something similar to give the script time to initialize. (Pause 1 will pause the script for 1 second)